# protractor, how to take specific element if others have the same className and tagName

Tags: javascript, class, protractor, cucumber, console.log

I'm using Cucumber and protractor with Javascript for automated tests. I need to test if is present the block Title on page, but I have others classes named "title" too. This field is editorial, so the text can be changed suddenly. How can I take this element correctly? 
PS: If someone have an idea or can tell me why console.log never works on my project it will be appreciate. Thank you!

Here my hmtl code:

```
<div class="titleH1"> 
  <div class="title-component"> 
    <div class="inner-container"> 
      ::before
      <span class="icon"> //this element has child. But here is closed
      <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
      (...)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using
`$('h1.title')` 
you can use
`$('div.titleH1 div.title-component div.inner-container h1.title')`
which is much more specific.

Issues with `console.log()` are often due to the async nature of javascript. Using `.then()` will likely solve that. EX:

```
$('element').getText().then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Here is a useful [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) about `.then()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
element(by.xpath("//div[@class='title-component']//h1[text()='Title A']")).isDisplayed();

// change `Title A` to the one you want to find
```